# Is Genesis 22:1 in contradiction with James 1:13?

Tags: contradiction

In Genesis 22:1, we see that God tempts Abraham.

> [Genesis 22:1](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-22-1/)
>
> And it came to pass after these things, that God did tempt Abraham, and said unto him, Abraham: and he said, Behold, here I am.

God explicitly talks to Abraham, so you can't say that God 'permitted the temptation' or something like that. However, in James 1:13 it says that God does never tempt people. Is this a contradiction?

> [James 1:13](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/James-1-13/)
>
> Let no man say when he is tempted, I am tempted of God: for God cannot be tempted with evil, neither tempteth he any man:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no contradiction here at all as the translation of the verb נִסָּה (nissah) in Gen 22:1 means  "to test, try", not "tempt to sin".  The same verb also occurs in Ex 15:25, 16:4, 17:2, 7, 20:20, Num 14:22, etc.  The full lexical meaning is given in the appendix below.

Thus, it remains true that God does not tempt to sin as per James 1:13.  However, God does test and try people as per the following:

- Rev 3:19 - Those I love, I **rebuke and discipline**. Therefore be earnest and repent.
- Heb 12:5 - And you have forgotten the exhortation that addresses you as sons: “My son, do not take lightly the discipline of the Lord, and do not lose heart when He rebukes you.
- James 1:12 - Blessed is the man who perseveres under **trial**, because when he has stood the **test**, he will receive the crown of life that God has promised to those who love Him.

Thus, the answer to the OP's question is in the previous verse, James 1:12, as quoted above.

**APPENDIX - BDB entry for נ־ס־ה**

> 1. **test, try** (synonym בחן), absolute 1 Samuel 17:39 (a sword); with בְּ Judges 7:39; Ecclesiastes 2:1; with accusative Daniel
>    1:12,14; accusative + בְּ 1 Kings 10:1, 2 Chronicles 9:1; Ecclesiastes
>    7:23.
> 2. **attempt, assay, try** to do a thing, with Infinitive Deuteronomy 4:34; Deuteronomy 28:56; with accusative Job 4:2 (venture a word).
> 3. **test, try, prove**, tempt [but not in modern sense of the word: see DrDeuteronomy 6:16; Psalms 453, 483]
>
> a. God tests or proves Abraham Genesis 22:1 (E), Israel Exodus 15:25;
> Exodus 20:20 (E), Exodus 16:4 (J), Deuteronomy 8:2,16; Deuteronomy
> 13:4; with בְּ Judges 2:22; Judges 3:1,4; tribe of Levi Deuteronomy
> 33:8 (poem); Hezekiah 2 Chronicles 32:31; psalmist Psalm 26:2.
>
> b. Israel tests, or tries God: Exodus 17:2,7; Numbers 14:22 (J),
> Deuteronomy 6:16; Psalm 78:18; Psalm 78:41; Psalm 78:56; Psalm 95:9;
> Psalm 106:14; so Ahaz, Isaiah 7:12.

Comment: The Hebrew is נִסָּה nissa not נָסָה nasa. BDB is confusingly worded, and actually beings  with "[נָסָה] verb Pi'el test, try (Late Hebrew id., Pi'el; ᵑ7 Pa'el נַסִּי;". The form נָסָה would be the qal verb of the same root, which is how they've chosen to index it, even though the verb does not appear in such a form in scripture